# How to implement Java soap client when server uses ADFS authentication?

Tags: java, soap, cxf, soapui, adfs

We are implementing a soap client in Java (using cxf wsdl2java). In previous projects the authentication has been based on either WS-Security or Basic HTTP Authentication. These are both easy to test in SoapUI and implement in java.

This time however, the server uses a Web Application Proxy which works as a reverse proxy, and ADFS (Active Directory Federation Services) for authentication purpose. I don't know the details of what this means, but what happens when opening the wsdl endpoint URL in a browser is that we get redirected to a login page similar to the office login page https://login.microsoftonline.com/ where you have manually click on the account type before entering credentials.

When logging in manually, we get redirected back to the wsdl endpoint with an appended ?authToken=xxx at the end and I think the token lasts for 1 hour. We have tried to ask the provider to use a more standard authentication, but for now this is the only thing we have. How do we approach this?

When trying to do a test request from SoapUI, we just get the complete html code of the login page in response. I see there is a Form Based Authentication option in SoapUI but it won't work since the login page has multiple account types and multiple username/password fields. The workaround for testing is just to login manually and use the authToken. But how can we automate this in the Java cxf client?

When connecting to the endpoint url in a browser, this is how the url looks after redirected to the login page:

[url to adfs seriver]/adfs/ls?version=1.0&action=signin&realm=urn%3AAppProxy%3Acom&appRealm=a10037ed-ca1e-e711-9436-00215a9b01ac&returnUrl=[wsdl endpoint url]&client-request-id=13A5B5A6-B574-0000-6FBA-A51374B5D201

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use SOAP to authenticate with ADFS via a login screen. This is because ADFS only supports WS-Fed or SAML-P or OpenID Connect (ADFS 4.0).

What you can do is use WS-Tust to do this.

WS-Fed supports two profile viz. passive (browser login screen) or active (web service / WCF). You need to use the latter.

There are a number of active profile endpoints that are available in ADFS. Not all are enabled by default so you may need to enable them.